# React and node js ::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When i try running in website and postman I received error : "connection refused" both Client and Server are running on diff ports

Client running on port:3000

```
 const handleSend = async (e) => {
    try {
      await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/fetchdata");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

Server running on port:4000

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const cors = require("cors");


app.get("/fetchdata", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  console.log("data");
  res.status(200).send("SUCCESS");
});



app.listen(
     (4000,() => {
     console.log("Server is listening on port 4000");
     })
    );
```

Server Package.json

```
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm run start --prefix ../client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\""
```

Error that i received

[image]

Comment: Use proxy attribute on client side in package.json or try changing the port number

Comment: Did you see the log `"Server is listening on port 4000"` on the terminal? And what I don't understand is, you send the request to HTTP://localhost:4000/api/fetchdata, but in the error, it is HTTP://localhost:4000/fetchdata

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh yes i saw the log in the terminal , /api is typo i forgot to remove it sorry

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not actually 'starting' your server.

Try this :

```
port = 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: I already listening to port 4000. I just forgot to include but still same error occurred

Answer (score 0):

Fixed adding "proxy": "http://localhost:4000" in React package.json